# Create iFrame of my Rails app for select websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, oauth

I have a Rails app that I would like to have customers embed in their website (via an iFrame or similar code) where they can submit a form and potentially view account info.

I currently don't use OAuth, but I was wondering how to log them in safely given the strict same-origin and CORS settings most sites use to prevent clickjacking and such.

My initial thought was giving the iFrame a webpage with a designated token in the url to specify it comes from a valid site but that could easily be copy-pasted by hackers. I'm pretty sure OAuth tries to prevent that but as mentioned I don't have that currently implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Iframe options for rails is restricted to same-origin. If you want to enable to external sites you can do it like this

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = { 'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL' }
```

This is will allow other sites to embed your site. If you want to restrict external sites. You can do that by adding following code it in your base controller.

```
response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://dummysite.com"
```

Keep this code in a method and call with before_action